# No packages at OpenMDAO binstar channel for Anaconda install

Tags: anaconda, conda, openmdao, binstar

It seems that the OpenMDAO packages have been removed from binstar? I have tried the following:

```
conda search -c https://conda.binstar.org/OpenMDAO openmdao
```

and

```
conda install -c openmdao openmdao
```

both resulting in the following:

```
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - openmdao

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/openmdao/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/openmdao/noarch
```

Was OpenMDAO Anaconda support removed or am I missing something?

Edit: Is this an incompatibility with win64 vs win32?

Edit 2: Yes that is the issue as outlined in their blog post:

> Caveat: Thanks to a bug in Traits (we’ve put in a bug report and await a new version), we can’t currently support an Anaconda install on a Windows2012_64bit installation unless you’re using a 32-bit Anaconda installed on the 64-bit architecture.  We will announce when that problem is resolved for our 64-bit Windows users.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install and use an older version of OpenMDAO, OpenMDAO 1.7.3? This is fine, as long as you know that we now have OpenMDAO 2.0.x.

If you have a reason for using 1.7.3, that's great. If you're just new to OpenMDAO, maybe you should read this article on choosing between 1 and 2:
http://openmdao.org/should-i-use-openmdao-1-or-2/

Comment: Thanks @kmarsteller. Yeah this is for automating conda package builds used as OpenMDAO components within a larger software package that has not been updated to work with OpenMDAO 2.x

Comment: @PhillyAI Your second edit should be the answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

As per Edit2. There is no update on 64-bit support that I can find.

> Caveat: Thanks to a bug in Traits (we’ve put in a bug report and await a new version), we can’t currently support an Anaconda install on a Windows2012_64bit installation unless you’re using a 32-bit Anaconda installed on the 64-bit architecture. We will announce when that problem is resolved for our 64-bit Windows users.